# Zipping the files in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, databricks

I am having some text files in S3 location. I am trying to compress and zip each text files in it. I was able to zip and compress it in Jupyter notebook by selecting the file from my local. While trying the same code in S3, its throwing error as file is missing. Could someone please help

Comment: Could you please show us the code you are trying to use, and the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 does not have a zip/compress function.

You will need to download the files, zip them on an Amazon EC2 instance or your own computer, then upload the result.